# Best way to populate a SAP table via c#

Tags: c#, abap, sap-dotnet-connector, cds

I'm trying to create a c# that application does a simple insert into a newly created sap table.

After a little bit of research I found out that I have two options:

- Using a CDS-View with `@OData.publish: true` and CRUD operations
- or using a bapi with the `SAP .NET Connector 3.0`.

Personally I think that the CDS view is much cleaner but I'm not getting the "create" operation to work. I found out that the cud operations are disabled on ABAP 7.50.

What do you think?

Thanks, Thomas

Comment: If CDS view CUD operations don't work for you, how about creating a small SAP Gateway OData Service for this purpose? So you can change to CDS view based CUD operations later without changing the client.

Comment: I see your point. But do I have to implement the $filter options and so on all by myself?
It's included on CDS views.

Comment: You're right, that would need extra development. My idea was to use the CDS view based OData service for READ operations and the self developed OData service only for CUD operations. A little ugly but the fastest way in development, when the CUD operations don't work for the CDS view generated OData service.

Comment: Ok thank you. That's the way I did it. 
It's a pity that there is no way to automate read options in a self-developed gateway service.

Answer (score 1):

There are more options. Use transaction `SICF` to create a REST endpoint. POST it data in JSON format. Use the `ID` XML transformation to map the data to an internal table with the same format as the database table in question. Use `MODIFY` or `INSERT` followed by `COMMIT WORK` to save the data.